# Saving PDF to Local Disk C#

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I am trying to save a PDF to the document folder. I have googled and came across a lot of resources but none of them worked for me. I have tried using showfiledialog which did not work. What I want is to save my PDF file to the documents folder. I need this done for a school project and this is the only part that has stumped me.  So far this is my code:

```
  private void savePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(nameTxtB.Text + "Repair.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

    Document document = new Document(); 
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);             
    pdfWriter.Open(); 
    PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
    document.Open(); 
    ...
```

Comment: What is the content of _nameTxtB.Text_?

Comment: Also, throw a `using` block around that Stream.

Comment: @Steve ``nameTxtB.text`` is the customers name which is used as a title of the PDF for organization if that's what your question is asking.

Comment: Define "did not work", please show errors etc, which line of code does it blow up on?  Also your code is far from complete.

Comment: In this way you are creating a file in whatever current directory your program is running. You need to prepend the path where you want to save your file. To save in the current user document directory you need to use the Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments enum. Many examples on this site to search for

Comment: @mxmissile the code has a lot of lines but I only put what was necessary to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your content (nameTxtB.Text) to Paragraph not to FileStream

```
   using System.IO;
   using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
   using iTextSharp.text;

 static void Main(string[] args) {
        // open the writer
            string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Repair.pdf");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        Document doc = new Document();

        //Create a New instance of PDFWriter Class for Output File

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
        //Open the Document
        doc.Open();
        //Add the content of Text File to PDF File

        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Document Content"));

        //Close the Document

        doc.Close();
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
    }
```